# Android Load library from path

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, selinux

I am checking on permissive and Enforcing mechanism of selinux(SE Linux) in Android 5.0.
I have placed .so file in /data/data/packageName/files/libtestcalc.so.

when the device is in permissive mode,
 System.load("/data/data/packageName/files/libtestcalc.so"); - works fine and I am able to access the methods of .so file with out any exceptions.

The same, System.load("/data/data/packageName/files/libtestcalc.so"); is not working when the device is in Enforcing mode and I am getting exception as follows.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: couldn't map "/data/data/packageName/files/libtestcalc.so" segment 1: Permission denied

I guess in both the modes, same call flow will occur.
I mean System.load(..)->Runtime.getRuntime().load(..)->Runtime.getRuntime(..).doload(..)->Runtime.getRuntime().nativeLoad(..)

@Runtime.java->doLoad(..) documentation mentioned as 
"nativeLoad should be synchronized so there's only one LD_LIBRARY_PATH in use regardless..."

When this LD_LIBRARY_PATH will get updated?

How android is differentiating the load files by modes?
Want to know other ways to load .so file from "/data/data/packageName/files/".

Comment: have you got any solution for this..??

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file to any location of your choice under your app's private internal storage folder, make sure it is marked read only and executable (not writable, especially by anyone else!). This is the only tree of locations typically writable by an application where executables are permitted.

You can determine the private folder location by calling getFilesDir() on an initialized Activity or Service Context.

There are a number of existing questions here which demonstrate mechanisms for file copying in Java.

Comment: It will be good idea to mention the source of your answer too.
I came across another answer exactly same as yours answered a year before.